# Using lstlistings environment inside of an \fbox

Tags: listings, framed

I have a function being used in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Change "article" to "report" to get rid of page number on title page
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{Pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,wrapfig}

% In case you need to adjust margins:
\topmargin=-0.45in      %
\evensidemargin=0in     %
\oddsidemargin=0in      %
\textwidth=6.5in        %
\textheight=9.0in       %
\headsep=0.25in         %


\newcommand{\sectionAnswer}[1]
  {% We put this space here to make sure we're disconnected from the previous
   % passage

   \noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{\columnwidth}#1\end{minipage}}%
   \enterProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}\exitProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}%
   \marginpar{\fbox{\homeworkSectionName}}%

   % We put the blank space above in order to make sure this
   % \marginpar gets correctly placed.
   }%
```

I then later use (I just want to add a few lines of MATLAB code, so notice the package mcode is used):

```
\sectionAnswer{
\begin{lstlisting}
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = a^2 + b^2;
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

I am aware that this is because listings (including verbatim content) cannot be passed as arguments to other functions/macros... So I am looking for a workaround? Ideally, I don't want to modify the original macro, because it works quite well, really. So, if I do modify it, `\fbox` would need to be replaced by something with identical properties.

---

Following advice from Werner, the macro is now:

```
\newcommand{\sectionAnswer}[1]
  {% We put this space here to make sure we're disconnected from the previous
   % passage

   \noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}#1\end{minipage}}
 % modify page width from \columnwidth to \dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule
   \enterProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}\exitProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}%
   \marginpar{\fbox{\homeworkSectionName}}%

   % We put the blank space above in order to make sure this
   % \marginpar gets correctly placed.
   }%
```

I should also note, that this is a modified template, based off [Ted Pavlic's](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_homework_tex_example.php).

Comment: If you are not doing any syntax highlighting or stuff like that (i.e., if straight verbatim is acceptable), then the `verbatimbox` package provides the way to do this.  (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99848/drawing-a-rectangle-box-around-code-fragment/99855#99855, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162870/verbatim-frame-latex-with-no-waste/162893#162893)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to maintain the current setup, then you can store the `lstlisting` inside a box before passing it to `\sectionAnswer`:

```
\newsavebox{\codebox}% For storing code in a box

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = a^2 + b^2;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\sectionAnswer{%
\usebox{\codebox}%
}
```

Note that your `minipage` width is probably better set as `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule`.